# Validação simples de Login com React Native

Tags: react-native

Boa tarde pessoal! Alguem pode me ajudar nessa validação para login simples com React native, só gostaria de verificar se os valores existem no banco, e caso houver, logar, minha api está assim:

import axios from 'axios';

const enviar = axios.create({
baseURL:"http://192.168.00.00:5001/api"
})

export default enviar

const [id, setId] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {

```
  async function BuscarLogins() {
    const response = await enviar.get("/Login/");
    console.log(response.data)
    setId(response.data)
  }
  BuscarLogins();
}, [])

const [usuario, setUsuario,] = useState("");
const [senha, setSenha,] = useState("");

function ValidaLogin() {
  let cont 
  let dados = {
    id : id,
    usuario : usuario,
    senha : senha
  }
    if(dados == 1){
      navigation.navigate('Menu')
    }else{
      alert("Login invalido!")
    }
  }
```

Comment: O que está dando errado?

Comment: Fica dando erro de Login Invalido com os valores certos

Comment: Veja seu código: você faz ```dados = { ...um objeto... }``` e na linha seguinte pergunta se dados é igual a "1". É claro que ele não é igual a 1 (pois é o objeto que você acabou de passar), portanto, ele cai no ```else``` e alerta "Login inválido". Note que isso sequer depende do resultado de sua requisição, pode até ser que ela tenha sido bem sucedida.

Comment: Muito obrigado César, consegui resolver